# counting level of nesting within a file folder

Tags: java, file, nested, filepath, subdirectory

when trying to count how many subdirectories there are in a file path, what would be the best way to do it?

For example, I want to check that file.txt in  /a/b/c/d/file.txt has only 3 subdirectories between itself and the root a folder.  Is there a way of doing this that I have not heard of?

Currently I am using a method to count how many parent directories are there up from file.txt by doing something similar to :

```
boolean lessThan3Subdirectories(File textFile){
File homeFile = new File (/a);
if (textFile.getParent()
           .getParentFile()
           .getParentFile()
           .getParentFile() 
            != homeFile){
return false; 
} else {
return true;
}
```

My issue with this method is that it is hardcoded to check 3 and always 3 but I actually don't care about how many parent directories it takes to get there as long as it is less than 3. (/a/b/file.txt is OK)

My other option would be to just get the file path string and count the amount of times "/" appears between the file and the home folder. The problem with that method though, is I can't account for file names that include escaped / (ie. "/")

Comment: Why can't you use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. here is the thing you can write a recursive function. i can give you a skeleton. This function will return you the depth at which your file is present.

```
        int recurFunc(String path, String fileNameToCheck){

            //1. count all the files in given directory
            //2. Write a for loop for each file checking if its a directory or file.
            //3. if its a directory call recurFunc with directory name appended. (return 1 + recurFunc(directorypath)). This will give you the depth
            //4. if its a file check if its your required file or not
            //5. if its your file return 0;else skip 

        }
```

Furthermore if you wanna restrict your search to 3 levels only pass the level to recurFunc(String path, String fileName, int level) and when going into a directory decrease the level by 1. When level is 0 just check if that level contains your file or not.